# remove csv header from using copy_from in python django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, csv

I am using following code:

```
def saveUploadedInventory(self, inventory_file,user_id):
        print "Inventory File"
        with open('uploaded_inventory_sheet.csv','wb+') as destination:
            for chunk in inventory_file.chunks():
                destination.write(chunk)
        print "Inventory Saved."
        f = open('uploaded_inventory_sheet.csv','rb')

        self.cur.copy_from(f, 'fk_payment_temp', sep=',', columns=('settlement_ref_no', 'order_type', 'fulfilment_type', 'seller_sku', 
            'wsn', 'order_id', 'order_item_id', 'order_date', 'dispatch_date', 'delivery_date', 
            'cancellation_date', 'settlement_date', 'order_status', 'quantity', 'order_item_value', 
            'sale_transaction_amount', 'discount_transaction_amount', 'refund', 
            'protection_fund', 'total_marketplace_fee', 'service_tax', 'swach_bharat_cess', 
            'settlement_value', 'commission_rate', 'commission', 'payment_rate', 
            'payment_fee', 'fee_discount', 'cancellation_fee', 'fixed_fee', 'emi_fee', 
            'total_weight', 'weight_type', 'shipping_fee', 'reverse_shipping_fee', 
            'shipping_zone', 'token_of_apology', 'pick_and_pack_fee', 'storage_fee', 
            'removal_fee', 'invoice_id', 'invoice_date', 'invoice_amount', 'sub_category', 
            'total_offer_amount', 'my_offer_share', 'flipkart_offer_share'))
```

It is giving following error:

> invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "Order Date"

that mean clear there should be some date instead of **Order Date**

here order date is header.

In postgresql:

```
COPY Table_Name FROM 'wheat_crop_data.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

how i can do this in python django ?

Comment: Is the `COPY FROM` the only way you accept, or creating the data via Django ORM is fine too?

Comment: I dont know about ORM. It is better for me if any solution with copy from

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then you should chop off the first line and feed the remainder to the cursor:

```
from StringIO import StringIO

with open('uploaded_inventory_sheet.csv') as f: 
    next(f) # skip the first line
    content = StringIO('\n'.join(line for line in f))
    self.cur.copy_from(content, ...)
```

Note this solution will hold the entire file in memory. If that is not an expected behavior, you may use the temporary intermediate file.

Comment: I am getting one more error. either i tell you here or i need to ask another question.

Comment: If it's a different error, you'd open another question, so that folks who will be looking for similar things will find an answer quicker.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786800/invalid-input-syntax-for-type-date-in-django-postgresql